# What is the semantics for choosing the reason when stopping a gen_server?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

The Erlang documentation states the following about gen_servers:

> ...
>
> Note that for any other reason than normal, shutdown, or {shutdown,Term} the gen_server is assumed to terminate due to an error and an error report is issued using error_logger:format/2.

Source: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:terminate-2

---

Since anything other than these three reasons are considered an error, I infer that the reasons `normal`, `shutdown` and `{shutdown, Reason}` are considered normal behavior.

I imagine the developers had a motive when choosing these three reasons for stopping a gen_server under normal conditions, but I'm not quite sure how to determine which one to use.

So when should I use `normal`, `shutdown` and `{shutdown, Reason}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `normal` if your server has finished its work and is terminating normally.

`shutdown` and `{shutdown, Reason}` are used by supervisor processes when they tell their children to terminate (e.g. the whole app is terminating or another process in the supervision tree has died and this is a one_for_all supervisor).

I use `normal` for all expected terminations and `{error, ErrorDescription}` for unexpected terminations.

Comment: The reason that supervisors use `shutdown` is that it actually is an error value. So if a child is not trapping exits then it will be killed. If it is trapping exits then it is expected to specially handle a `shutdown` exit signal from its parent (supervisor) and terminate cleanly. This is handled by OTP behaviours so there is no need to do it yourself.